# Discord Bot deleting channels from list

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python right now and wanted to add a feature that deletes all the channels in a guild that are in a list of channel names. I tried going trough all the channels that are stored in the "ctx.message.guild.channel" list and check if they are in my channel_names list but it doesn't find the channel so nothing happens. Thanks for helping me already!

```
channel_names = ["channel1","channel2","channel3"]

@commands.command()
async def clear(self, ctx):
     for channel in list(ctx.message.guild.channel):
           if channel in channel_names:
                await channel.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get text channels you must use [text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.Guild.text_channels) then text_channel.name to compare.

```py
channel_names = ["channel1","channel2","channel3"]

@commands.command()
async def clear(self, ctx):
     for channel in list(ctx.message.guild.text_channels):
           if channel.name in channel_names:
                await channel.delete()
```